# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'registerForm' available as request attribute

Tags: spring

I am getting this error.I have tried allot but could not understand what it means?
worker class which interacts with db:

```
public class EmpLeaveApplyWorker{

        private Connection con;
        private PreparedStatement pstmt;
            public boolean validateUser(LeaveApplyForm leaveapplyform){
                            try{
                    con=DBConnection.getConnection();
    //              String query="select MAX(user_id)from emplogin";
                    String query1 = "insert into empLeave(LeaveType,leavePeriod,FirstApprover,finalApprover) values(?,?,?,?)";
                    //String query2 = "insert into emplogin(user_id) values(?)";
                    System.out.println("------Not able to go ahead---in worker");   pstmt=con.prepareStatement(query1);
                //  String empName=registerForm.getName()+" "+registerForm.getMname()+" "+registerForm.getLname();
                    pstmt.setString(1, leaveapplyform.getLeaveType());
                    pstmt.setString(2,leaveapplyform.getLeavePeriod() );                            
                    pstmt.setString(3, leaveapplyform.getFirstApprover());
                    pstmt.setString(4, leaveapplyform.getFinalApprover());

    //              pstmt.executeUpdate();
                    System.out.println("$--------------------details may have updated successfully -----------------------check that out---------------");
                    int status= pstmt.executeUpdate();

    /*              pstmt=con.prepareStatement(query2); 
                    pstmt.setString(2, leaveapplyform.getPassword());
    */              
                     pstmt.executeUpdate();
                     if(status>0){
                         System.out.println("Employee Account Created Scuucessfully");
                     }

                }catch(Exception e)
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                return false;}              
    /*      public int getEmpNumber(){
                try{
                    con=DBConnection.getConnection();
                    String query="select MAX(user_id)from emplogin";
                    PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement(query);
                    ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
                    if(rs.next()){
                        return rs.getInt(1);
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return 0;
            }*/}


I am posting controller class and dispatcher-servlet.xml is configured and it is working working fine but the problem is with controller,cany any one solve this error?:



 @Controller
        public class EmpLeaveApplyController 
        {
            static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(EmpLeaveApplyController.class.getName());
            @RequestMapping(value = "/leaveapplyform", method = RequestMethod.GET)
               public String showForm(ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request) 
               {
                 log.info("Inside Controller returning to leaveapplyform page....");
                 LeaveApplyForm leaveapplyform =  new LeaveApplyForm();
                model.put("leaveapplyform", leaveapplyform);    

                /*EmpLeaveApplyWorker worker1=new EmpLeaveApplyWorker();*/
            return GlobalConstants.LEAVE_APPLY; 
               }
                /*
                int emp_id=worker1.getEmpNumber();
                if(emp_id > 0){
                CommonDTOBean dtoBean=new CommonDTOBean();
                dtoBean.setEmp_id(emp_id);
                registerForm.setEmpID(emp_id);
                HttpSession session=request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("dtoBean", dtoBean);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Error While getting the emp id ");
                }
                return GlobalConstants.REGISTER_PAGE;
               }
                  */
            @RequestMapping(value = "/leaveapplyform" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
            public String processForm(@ModelAttribute("leaveapplyform") LeaveApplyForm leaveapplyform, BindingResult result,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap model)
            {
                System.out.println("-------I think can not go head---------------");
                leaveapplyform = (LeaveApplyForm) model.get("leaveapplyform");
                /*if(result.hasErrors()){
                    return GlobalConstants.ERRORPAGE;
                }*/
                EmpLeaveApplyWorker worker=new EmpLeaveApplyWorker();
                boolean status=worker.validateUser(leaveapplyform);
                if(status)
                {
                    System.out.println("------------------came to the last point of todays task-------------------------------");
                    return GlobalConstants.HOME_PAGE;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("------do not come here------------------");
                    return GlobalConstants.REGISTER_PAGE;
                }           }
        }
```

I created all the setter and getter for all required variables.And If possible,tell me where I am wrong?

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>


<html> 
<head>  
<title> Application </title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style2.css">
</head>
<body background="Background.gif">



<h2> Application Form </h2> 
<div id="align">  

<form:form method="POST" action="leaveapplyform.do"  commandName="leaveapplyform" modelAttribute="leaveapplyform"> 


<spring:message code="label.leaveType"/>
<form:select path="LeaveType" id="date">
<form:option value="Five Live Carry Forward"></form:option>
<form:option value="Live Carry Forward"></form:option>
<form:option value="Hello"></form:option></form:select>

        <spring:message code="label.leavePeriod"/>
        <form:select path="leavePeriod" name="leavePeriod" id="choice" class="date" onchange="ShowReg(this.selectedIndex)">
        <form:option value="Platinum Package" ></form:option>
        <form:option value="Gold Package"></form:option></form:select>

        <div id="Platinum" style="display:none">
        <div class="style12"><spring:message code="label.selectHours" /></div>
        <form:select path="selectHours" name="eselect" id="selecte" class="date" onchange="ShowSkill(this.selectedIndex)">
        <form:option selected="selected" value="event_select"></form:option>
        <form:option value="event_golf"></form:option>
        <form:option value="event_other"></form:option>
        <form:option value="event_golf"></form:option>
        <form:option value="event_other"></form:option></form:select>
        </div>
<div id="Gold" style="display:none">
</div>

        <spring:message code="label.firstApprover"/>
        <form:select path="firstApprover"name="firstApprover" id="date">
        <form:option value="Full Day " ></form:option>
        <form:option value="Half Day"></form:option>
        </form:select>

        <spring:message code="label.finalApprover"/>
        <form:select path="finalApprover" id="date" name="finalApprover" >
        <form:option value="Full Day " >Zafar .M . </form:option>
        <form:option value="Half Day">Raut . P</form:option></form:select>



    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" name="reset"class="reset" value="Reset">




    </form:form>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowReg(op) {
        document.getElementById('Platinum').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('Gold').style.display = 'none';

        if (op == 1) {
            document.getElementById('Platinum').style.display = "block";
        }
        if (op == 2) {
            document.getElementById('Gold').style.display = "block";
        }

    }
    function ShowSkill(op) {
        document.getElementById('golf').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'none';

        if (op == 1) {
            document.getElementById('golf').style.display = "block";
        }
        if (op == 2) {
            document.getElementById('other').style.display = "block";
        }

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show your jsp where form is present.

Comment: In your controller you use `leaveapplyform`, judging frmo the error in your jsp you use `registerForm`. Names are different, hence the error. Your `processForm` method is also flawed you shouldn't get the form from the model, it is already part of your method signature.

Comment: I am using the same leaveapplyform at all places to avoid confusion.

Comment: How you are displaying your form?? I mean suppose you have link "Apply" and on clicking that it should have url as "/leaveapplyform"

Comment: means what?I didn't get it?

Comment: Is problem with jsp page or with contoller?

Comment: See when we have showForm will be called when you have getRequest....but you dont have any getRequest or may be having.

Comment: ya,right onsubmit the page will dispaly success message,One more thing as soon as I click onsubmit the value of thses fields are getting save d on database but the next page is not getting display.

Comment: Please System.out.println(status) in process form and check or bug where control is going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with your `showForm()` method.

**Probable Mistake 1:**

May be in your jsp you have given name as "registerForm"

```
<form:form modelAttribute="registerForm"> //Change to leaveapplyform
```

or

```
<form:form commandName="registerForm">
```

And here you are writing as

```
 model.put("leaveapplyform", leaveapplyform);
```

Change it either in jsp or here.

**Probable Mistake 2** and can say **Actual mistake**

your `validateUser()` is always returning `false`;

Hence in processForm your control is going to

```
 else{
       System.out.println("------do not come here------------------");
       return GlobalConstants.REGISTER_PAGE;
     }
```

So here your view set is register***.jsp which may have

```
<form:form commandName="registerForm">
```

So you don't have `registerForm` Command coming from `processForm`.

So inorder to make it work make this change in your `validateUser()` method.

```
 if(status>0){
     
     System.out.println("Employee Account Created Scuucessfully");
     return true;
 }
```